# How to group columns alphabetically with tabulate module?

Tags: python, python-2.6

I am using the `tabulate` module to print information nicely at the console. I am using python 2.6

I currently have this:

```
+-------------------------------+
|   Task  |  Status  |  Rating  |
|---------+---------------------+
|    A    |  Done    |   Good   |
|    B    |  Done    |   Bad    |
|    C    |  Pending |          |
|    D    |  Done    |   Good   |
+---------+----------+----------+
```

I want to go to this:

```
+-------------------------------+
|   Task  |  Status  |  Rating  |
|---------+---------------------+
|    A    |  Done    |   Good   |
|    B    |  Done    |   Bad    |
|    D    |  Done    |   Good   |
|    C    |  Pending |          |
+---------+----------+----------+
```

So that all of the `Done`s are grouped together.

Currently the tabulate receives a dictionary and I unpack the values like this:

```
def generate_table(data):
    table = []
    headers = ['Task', 'Status', 'Rating']

    for key, value in data.iteritems():
        print key, value

        if 'Rating' in value:
            m, l = value['Status'], value['Rating']
            m = m.split('/')[-1]
            temp = [key,m,l]
            table.append(temp)
        else:
            m, l = value['Status'], None
            m = m.split('/')[-1]
            temp = [key,m,l]
            table.append(temp)

    print tabulate(table, headers, tablefmt="psql")
```

Comment: In your example, the desired output swaps the pending task from C to D. Is this intentional?

Comment: You can for sure avoid the `if` `else` if you use `value.get('Rating',None)`, which assigns a default (`None` in this case) when the key (`'Rating'` in this case) is not part of the dictionary. For the rest, one can only answer once you respond to @languitar

Comment: @languitar no that was a mistake. Good catch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sort your resulting table by Status column after your for loop:

`sorted(table, key=lambda status: status[1])`

This will effectively "group" the values alphabetically.